# I am looking for a clean HTML tutorial

Tags: css, layout, html

I've been doing web programming from 1999 to 2004 and it looks like a lot has changed.  The layout is no longer done with tables, but with DIVs, etc...

I am looking for a tutorial that combines CSS and HTML and DIVs, etc... and teaches you how to layout a page.

I don't want a tutorial that focuses on a specific one technology, but more of a holistic approach.  And for whatever reason I am not find that at all.

Comment: Why not just look at csszengarden for examples of what CSS can do, if that is a big concern of yours.  There have been many changes in the past 5 years, as javascript has become more common also.

Comment: CSS Zen Garden is a great example of how powerful CSS can be, but it's really not the best starting-out type of site. There's an emphasis on form over function - most of the techniques used to create the gorgeous versions of the site aren't easily applicable to a full fledged website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're up for buying or borrowing a book, I would suggest *[Designing With Web Standards](http://www.zeldman.com/dwws/)* by Jeffrey Zeldman.

I would also highly suggest Zeldman's [A List Apart](http:///www.alistapart.com) for articles, particularly the [Code:CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/topics/code/css/) and [Code:HTML and XHTML](http://www.alistapart.com/topics/code/htmlxhtml/) sections to cover what you're looking for. There's a lot to learn; a few good articles to start with might be:

- [How to Grok Web Standards](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/grokwebstandards/)
- [In Search of the Holy Grail](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/)
- [Fix Your Site with the Right DOCTYPE!](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/)
- [12 Lessons for Those Afraid of CSS and Standards](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/12lessonsCSSandstandards/)

Comment: A List Apart is indeed one of the best!

Comment: Feel free to post the links when you've earned enough points.

Comment: I would have never survived the "Tables are evil" transition without A List Apart.

Answer (score 2):

I like [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) because it has these "try it" boxes where you can see what happens instantly. It's very helpful.

Comment: W3schools teaches anything but proper CSS layout. Their site is done with tables, for god's sake.

Comment: Just to clarify, I wasn't suggesting looking at the source code of that site but the tutorials they offer.

Comment: The tutorials aren't much good either. http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend [this one](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-multi-column-liquid-layouts) by Matthew James. It's very clean, descriptive and follows all the standards

Answer (score 2):

The [Opera WSC](http://wsc.opera.com/) is good. [HTML Dog](http://htmldog.com/) isn't bad either.

Comment: HTML Dog is an excellent "starter" resource and I always direct everyone who wants to learn HTML/CSS to their tutorial series.